# Apache CXF SOAP client , using generated stubs in https

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I am generating a SOAP client for a SOAP webservice. I created Java stubs and when I tried executing I got an error:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:`
```

I tried running InstallCert but it didn't work even after that.

```
INFO: The cipher suite filters have not been configured, falling back to default filters.
4 Nov, 2011 1:07:52 AM org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils getCiphersFromList
INFO: The cipher suites have been set to SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5.  
4 Nov, 2011 1:07:53 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doIntercept
INFO: Interceptor has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:296)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:242)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:178)
    at $Proxy36.updateValues(Unknown Source)
    at com.siebel.customui.UpdateStatus_UpdateStatus_Client.main(UpdateStatus_UpdateStatus_Client.java:62)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1611)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:187)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:181)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1035)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:124)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:516)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:454)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1112)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1139)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1123)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:904)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1834)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1792)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1852)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:593)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:294)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:200)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1014)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:289)
    ... 32 more
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:199)
    at $Proxy36.updateValues(Unknown Source)
    at com.siebel.customui.UpdateStatus_UpdateStatus_Client.main(UpdateStatus_UpdateStatus_Client.java:62)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:296)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:242)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:178)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1611)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:187)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:181)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1035)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:124)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:516)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:454)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1112)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1139)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1123)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:904)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1834)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1792)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1852)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:593)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:294)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:200)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1014)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:289)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: This line — `Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` — is the most relevant diagnostic, it seems.

Comment: How was the server's SSL certificate generated?

Comment: server is not under our control. server uses an internally generated certificate.

Comment: interesting thing is that it works fine with SoapUi tool. I did nt do any keytool trusted certificate stuff.  If soapui can do it why cant my code.

Comment: SoapUI might just be not enforcing any security checks at all. For a debugging tool, that wouldn't be at all surprising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buried inside that stack trace (near the end) is this *critical* information:

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

This indicates that the exception is due to the server certificate not being trusted. X.509 certificates contain a description of a chain of trust (e.g., A signed the certificate of B, B signed the server certificate) where each part is done as a certificate (yes, they nest). For that chain to be valid, some certificate on the chain (typically the root one, A in my example above) must be trusted *by the client*, as that protects against a whole class of trivial attacks (anyone at all can create a certificate or certificate chain; the software to do so is freely available).

The documentation on how to configure CXF with trust information is a little sparse, but here's the summary. First, put the server certificate (or the topmost certificate upstream of it if it isn't self-signed) in a JKS-format keystore (e.g., `serverIdentity.jks`, secured with password `jkspass`). Secondly, configure CXF's http conduit with the information about what to trust:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
  xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security
      http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
      http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

   <http:conduit name="*.http-conduit"> <!-- replace with real conduit name -->
       <http:tlsClientParameters>
          <sec:trustManagers>
              <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="jkspass"
                   file="my/file/dir/serverIdentity.jks"/>
          </sec:trustManagers>
      </http:tlsClientParameters>

      <!-- assume user/pass over https; common case -->
      <http:authorization>
         <sec:UserName>foo</sec:UserName>
         <sec:Password>bar</sec:Password>
      </http:authorization>

      <!-- Below is where normal http control goes -->
      <http:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive"/>
   </http:conduit>
</beans>
```

The above is based on the examples in the [CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html) which also describes many other options you might need. For example, you might need to add the `disableCNcheck="true"` attribute definition to the `<http:tlsClientParameters>` element; if you're using directly-known-and-trusted self-signed certificates, you've very little need to ensure that the expected hostname of the service matches the relevant sub-field of the server certificate's common name (CN) field. Or maybe you need to provide a cryptographic client identity (for which, see the examples in that link).